# Magento Order Export XML

Tags: php, xml, magento, export

I am looking for a php file, that can export magento orders to XML format. All the orders.

But not into MS-XML, I need a simple XML exactly like this below.

I need it to be grouped, with more levels. I'm stuck with this since weeks :( Someone please help me! Thank you!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2" ?>
<Header>
 <Order_datas>
  <Order_nr>MR4001</Order_nr>
  <Datum>2014.01.03 13:15:49</Datum>
  <Payment_method>wire_transf</Payment_method>
  <Shipping_method>posta</Szallitasi_mod>
  <Customer_note></Customer_note>
  <Header_Customer>
   <Customer_name>Minta Péter</Customer_name>
   <Customer_zip>1037</Customer_zip>
   <Customer_city>Budapest</Customer_city>
   <Customer_address>Duna u. 5.</Customer_address>
   <Shipping_name>Minta Péter</Shipping_name>
   <Shipping_zip>1037</Shipping_zip>
   <Shipping_city>Budapest</Shipping_city>
   <Shipping_address>Duna u. 5.</Shipping_address>
   <Telefon></Telefon>
   <Email>mintapeter@mintapeter.hu</Email>
   <VATNR></VATNR>
  </Header_Customer>
  <Items>
   <Ordered_Items>
    <Product_name>Férfi cipő</Product_name>
    <ID>77866684</ID>
    <SKU></SKU>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
    <QTYINC>pár</QTYINC>
    <Netto_price>20000</Netto_price>
    <TAX>27%</TAX>
    <Discount_percentage>0</Discount_percentage>
   </Ordered_Items>
  </Items>
 </Order_datas>
 <Order_datas>
  <Order_nr>MR4002</Order_nr>
  <Datum>2014.01.04 12:05:49</Datum>
  <Payment_method>készpénz</Payment_method>
  <Shipping_method>személyes átvétel</Szallitasi_mod>
  <Customer_note></Customer_note>
  <Header_Customer>
   <Customer_name>Példa Gábor</Customer_name>
   <Customer_zip>5000</Customer_zip>
   <Customer_city>Szolnok</Customer_city>
   <Customer_address>Somos u. 23.</Customer_address>
   <Shipping_name>Példa Gábor</Shipping_name>
   <Shipping_zip>5000</Shipping_zip>
   <Shipping_city>Szolnok</Shipping_city>
   <Shipping_address>Somos u. 23.</Shipping_address>
   <Telefon>06-70-999-8888</Telefon>
   <Email>pelda.gabor@gmail.com</Email>
   <VATNR></VATNR>
  </Header_Customer>
  <Items>
   <Ordered_Items>
    <Product_name>Villanykapcsoló</Product_name>
    <ID>12345687</ID>
    <SKU></SKU>
    <QTY>2</QTY>
    <QTYINC>db</QTYINC>
    <Netto_price>1000</Netto_price>
    <TAX>27%</TAX>
    <Discount_percentage>0</Discount_percentage>
   </Ordered_Items>
  </Items>
 </Order_datas>
 <Order_datas>
  <Order_nr>MR4003</Order_nr>
  <Datum>2014.01.04 16:01:14</Datum>
  <Payment_method>wire_transf</Payment_method>
  <Shipping_method>posta</Szallitasi_mod>
  <Customer_note></Customer_note>
  <Header_Customer>
   <Customer_name>Kitalált Cég Bt.</Customer_name>
   <Customer_zip>1113</Customer_zip>
   <Customer_city>Budapest</Customer_city>
   <Customer_address>Gesztenye u. 45.</Customer_address>
   <Shipping_name>Fodor Anikó</Shipping_name>
   <Shipping_zip>1113</Shipping_zip>
   <Shipping_city>Budapest</Shipping_city>
   <Shipping_address>Dermák u. 11.</Shipping_address>
   <Telefon></Telefon>
   <Email>kitalalt.ceg.bt@gmail.com</Email>
   <VATNR>13781111-2-43</VATNR>
  </Header_Customer>
  <Items>
   <Ordered_Items>
    <Product_name>Férfi cipő</Product_name>
    <ID>77866684</ID>
    <SKU></SKU>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
    <QTYINC>pár</QTYINC>
    <Netto_price>20000</Netto_price>
    <TAX>27%</TAX>
    <Discount_percentage>0</Discount_percentage>
   </Ordered_Items>
   <Ordered_Items>
    <Product_name>Női ruha</Product_name>
    <ID>12345694</ID>
    <SKU></SKU>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
    <QTYINC>db</QTYINC>
    <Netto_price>10000</Netto_price>
    <TAX>27%</TAX>
    <Discount_percentage>0</Discount_percentage>
   </Ordered_Items>
  </Items>
 </Order_datas>
</Header>
```

Comment: Have you considered the SOAP API? There's an endpoint which lets you do exactly this (list orders). http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create your own module with a Model which can be called everywhere (Observer, shell, cron ...) and on this model add a function like above :

```
public function send() {
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('processing', 'paid')));

   $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
   $ordersElmt = $dom->createElement('header');
   foreach ($orders as $order) { /** @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */
            $orderElmt = $dom->createElement('Order_datas');
            $orderIdElmt = $dom->createElement('Order_nr', $order->getId());
// And add your other nodes
            $ordersElmt->appendChild($orderElmt);
            }
   $dom->save("/path/to/your/folder/file.xml");
        }
```

You 'll need to change the order status in the code somewhere if you dont want to have every orders at every launch
    $order->setStatus("yourstatus");

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, but I'm a bit sad now, I'm stuck on this since weeks. There is a magento built in solution here: 

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html

This XML output would be the best for me. (ordered products are under each other at every order)

But I think this still needs a php file to trigger the API and produce an XML file as output.. And this PHP file must be programmed, there's not any template around. :( And I'm not a programmer. Does anyone has a php file for this REST APi maybe?

Comment: In this code that you wrote above, how do I add another notes? Do I call them like this? 

 $order->getId());
 $order->getSKU());
 $order->getbilling_firstname());

or something, right?

Comment: Order->getSomething() will just retrieve the data from the current order, you will need to add it to the XML dom, like this: ` $orderIdElmt = $dom->createElement('Datum', $order->getCreatedAt());`

Comment: I didn't find anything free to create personnal XML structure from magento, either you paid for it, or you try this by yourself. I can help a bit. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I know... And even if you pay for something, still does not work the way you need... I know... Thanks for your help, I hope I can manage it with your code! David

Comment: I tried your code. It requires to define a class first (read on a forum) or remove public word. Yes. But it returns a blank page, Even I adjusted the path for the xml. Not working :(

Comment: it depends on how do you want your output, as file? as HTML?

Comment: I wanna have an XML file saved to localhost or server.  But a saved XML file. But when I try the code, it does not even produce an xml in browser, and not saving the file. Returns a blank page. Did I miss something? What else do I have to add to the code to display or save the xml itself? I can make the nodes myself I think, I just should start somewhere... Thank you!

Comment: OK good, by this way you should got a file on your webserver. For avoiding any user too launch it, this script can't be executed from any page. Rather use (if on linux) `php /path/to/shell/file.php ` . Create a file in the shell folder and write this in : ` require_once 'abstract.php'; 

class Xml_Shell_Import extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{ //your send function here
}
$shell = new Xml_Shell_Import();
$shell->send(); `

Comment: Don't forget to change the path to your own!

Comment: Sorry, I am not a programmer, I just have to solve this somehow.. Now I did what you told me, and: 

Fatal error: Class Xml_Shell_Import contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Shell_Abstract::run) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shell\exportalo.php on line 3

Comment: Yes my bad, rename the function from send to run and also the $shell->send() to $shell->run() . You are doing great don't worry.

Comment: Now it runs (changed some lines in host/shell/abstract.php) through browser, but returns an empty xml file. Not adding any header, or any element of the orders... Just this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: I also tried to run via shell, it runs through, but still an empty xml.. :( If I just could produce an xml with one or two values in it, I would be soo happy.

Comment: Now we talk with meme? My bad another time, i've forgotten another line ` $dom->appendChild($ordersElmt); ` which is just under  ` $ordersElmt = $dom->createElement('header'); `

Comment: Update: I figured out the forgotten line, but it seems like this method can extract only the order ID? I added another child, and tried to extract product SKU's into the XML, and nothing happens. with the getSku method instead of getId. Do you have any idea? The order ID's are coming, but the sku's not, and even the customer firstname etc.. with getBilling_address etc.

Comment: I added here somewhere. I hope you see it. Added as a new answer, I do not know if system allows or not to post as a new answer. Yes it is below this discussion. Produces an xml: 

<Order_number>4</Order_number>
<Customer_firstname/>
<Order_number>5</Order_number>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php'; 
class dom_Shell_Import extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {  


public function run() {
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
 
 ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending', 'paid')));
 #->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', array('in' => array()));
     
 
            

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
 $header = $dom->createElement("header");
    $header = $dom->appendChild($header);

   foreach ($orders as $order) { 
    
 $Order_number = $dom->createElement("Order_number", $order->getid());
    $Order_number = $header->appendChild($Order_number);
 
 $Customer_firstname = $dom->createElement("Customer_firstname", $order->getFirstname());
    $Customer_firstname = $header->appendChild($Customer_firstname);  
   
            }
   $dom->save("file.xml");
        }
 
 }$shell = new dom_Shell_Import(); $shell->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require_once 'abstract.php';

class dom_Shell_Import extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {

public function run() {
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending', 'paid')));
    #->addFieldToFilter('increment_id', array('in' => array()));

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $header = $dom->createElement("header");
    $dom->appendChild($header);

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        $order_data = $dom->createElement("Order_datas");
        $header->appendChild($order_data);
        /*order Data */
        $Order_number = $dom->createElement("Order_number", $order->getIncrementId());
        $Order_date = $dom->createElement("Datum", $order->getCreatedAt());
        $order_data->appendChild($Order_number);
        $order_data->appendChild($Order_date);

        /* Customer Data */
        $customer_header = $dom->createElement("Header_Customer");
        $order_data->appendChild($customer_header);

        $Customer_name = $dom->createElement("Customer_name", $order->getCustomerName());
        $customer_header->appendChild($Customer_name);
        /* products data */
        $Items = $dom->createElement("Items");
        $order_data->appendChild($Items);
        $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($ordered_items as $ordered_item) { /*loop throught the ordered item */
            $Ordered_Items = $dom->createElement("Ordered_Items");
            $Items->appendChild($Ordered_Items);
            $sku = $dom->createElement("SKU", $ordered_item->getSku());
            $Ordered_Items->appendChild($sku);
            $qty = $dom->createElement("QTY", (int) $ordered_item->getQtyOrdered());
            $Ordered_Items->appendChild($qty);
        }
    }
    $dom->save("file.xml");
}

}

$shell = new dom_Shell_Import();
$shell->run();
```

I added some line to be more readeable. Now with this you should have some more line to your xml file

Comment: Nice, thank you. It works more or less. Now I should have a header for items, and under this header, I should have the ordered products. Product SKU would be enough. No need price, or anything. How to get the order's sku's? getSKU not working.. :(

Comment: I edited my answer, for getting item data, you have to retreive them and loop on every item for the order then you can get every SKU. I added the QTY to your XML, i tought it would be usefull

Comment: I think now everything works like a charm. :) I have only one question left: how to get the payment method? I do not need anything else, just add one more line under order_number and order_date with payment_method. Already done shipping method, it works with getshppingmethod instance. Please let me know this last answer. :) Thanks

Comment: Also getCustomerName works, but I'm unable to gain any other data, like shipping address, billing address, zip code, phone number, etc. getBillingAddress, getcustomeraddres, etc. not working.. I tried everything.

Comment: something like `          $payment_method_code = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode(); `

Comment: `           $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
            $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); ` and then with those you can retrieve data like ` $billingAddress->getPostcode() `

Comment: Bhaaaa, this was my fault. Works :D I was pasting to a wrong place. :D For your help for me, you deserve a 6 pack of beer now! Thank you for your help very much!

Comment: Have you inserted it after the first foreach? $order should be initialised

Comment: I do not know what I did, but now it works, and I saved the php file to 10 pendrives, and 2 CD-R :D Now everything should work I think. Thank you again!

Comment: haha ok, no problem! I spend the time at a boring formation and i've almost been teached by stackoverflow for everything I know on magento, so it's my turn now.

Comment: Hahaha protect it like your preciouuuuuus